# Mathjax broken? Is it just me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

Is Mathjax rendering broken on the main site, or is it just me?

Is cdn.mathjax,org timing out for others?

Comment: It's not timing out for me, but I am getting 400 "Bad Request" responses, so yes, something does seem to be up with MathJax. I'll look into it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: For future reference it helps if you can report that you *have* done things like clearing the cache and force-reloading the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TeX might not render (GoDaddy was hacked)

is what is says on the Math SE page.

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy

*On 10 September 2012 Go Daddy was hit by a severe denial-of-service attack (DoS) that caused all of its services to become unavailable for several hours. A member of the Anonymous claimed responsibility for the attack that caused outages of thousands of websites*

Their Twitter says they are working on it.